# Jquery - Change Behavior Of Next Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an image gallery.   The behavior I want is when the page is loaded, the user will see just the first title.  When they click next the description for the first image will appear.   When they click next again, all previous titles and descriptions will be hidden and the 2nd title will appear.  clicking next again will show the 2nd description and so on.

I don't know javascript at all.  I wrote this sample code to show the behavior I want. Ideally I can specify the max # of titles so I can grey out the next button when it is on the last item.

```
    <button id="b1">Next</button>
    <button id="b2" style="display:none;">Next</button>
    <button id="b3" style="display:none;">Next</button>
    <div class="description" id="1t">This is Title 1</div>
    <div class="title" id="1d" style="display:none;">This is description # 1</div>
    <div class="description" id="2t" style="display:none;">This is Title 2</div>
    <div class="title" id="2d" style="display:none;">This is description # 2</div>
    <div class="description" id="3t" style="display:none;">This is Title 3</div>
    <div class="title" id="3d" style="display:none;">This is description # 3</div>

    <script>
    $("#b1").click(function () {
        $(".title").hide();
        $(".description").hide();
        $("button").hide();
        $("#1t").show();
        $("#1d").show();
        $("#b2").show();    
    });

    $("#b2").click(function () {
        $(".title").hide();
        $(".description").hide();
        $("button").hide();
        $("#2t").show();
        $("#b3").show();    
    });

    $("#b3").click(function () {
        $(".title").hide();
        $(".description").hide();
        $("button").hide();
        $("#2t").show();
        $("#2d").show();    
    });


    </script>
```

Comment: Could button 4 not just be styled to be greyed out originally?

Comment: The styling of the buttons is easy for me.  I need to understand the best way to keep track of the state of the page ( which title is being displayed and whether the description is being displayed ) and then programmatically change the button to show the right content when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't efficient programming but after a lot of research I got it to work.   Here is what I came up with.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>


        <div style="width: 500px;">
          <div style="float:left;">
            <a href="#"><div id="prevBtn" pageNum="<?=$pageNum?>" pageType="description" style="background-color: grey; padding: 5px; color: #fff; width: 100px;">Previous</div></a>
          </div>

          <div style="float:right;">
            <a href="#"><div id="nextBtn" pageNum="<?=$pageNum?>" pageType="description" style="background-color: grey; padding: 5px; color: #fff; width: 100px;">Next</div></a>
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>

          <div class="description" id="1t">This is Title 1</div>
          <div class="title" id="1d" style="display:none;">This is description # 1</div>


        </div>

          <script>

          $("#nextBtn").click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              var pageNum = $("#nextBtn").attr("pageNum");
              var pageNumber = Number($("#nextBtn").attr("pageNum"));
              var pageType = $("#nextBtn").attr("pageType");

              if(pageNumber > <?=$totalPages?>) {
                console.log("Too many pages\n\n");
              } else if(pageNumber < 1) {
                console.log("Too few pages\n\n");

              } else {

                if( pageType == "description" ){
                  $("#1d").show();
                  pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;

                  pageType = "title";
                }else{
                  pageType = "description";
                  $("#1d").hide();

                }
                $("#nextBtn").attr("pageNum", pageNumber);
                $("#nextBtn").attr("pageType", pageType);

                document.getElementById("1t").innerHTML = "Title " + pageNum;
                document.getElementById("1d").innerHTML = "Description " + pageNum;
              }
              console.log("Page Number " + pageNum);
              console.log("Page Type " + pageType);
          });


          $("#prevBtn").click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              var pageNum = $("#prevBtn").attr("pageNum");
              var pageNumber = Number($("#prevBtn").attr("pageNum"));
              var pageType = $("#prevBtn").attr("pageType");

              if(pageNumber > <?=$totalPages?>) {
                console.log("Too many pages\n\n");
              } else if(pageNumber < 1) {
                console.log("Too few pages\n\n");

              } else {

                if( pageType == "description" ){
                  $("#1d").show();

                  pageType = "title";
                }else{
                  pageType = "description";
                  $("#1d").hide();
                  pageNumber = pageNumber - 1;


                }
                $("#prevBtn").attr("pageNum", pageNumber);
                $("#prevBtn").attr("pageType", pageType);

                document.getElementById("1t").innerHTML = "Title " + pageNum;
                document.getElementById("1d").innerHTML = "Description " + pageNum;

              }

              console.log("Page Number " + pageNum);
              console.log("Page Type " + pageType);
          });



          </script>





  </body>
  </html>
```